# Using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to deserialize Json to a C# class

Tags: c#, json

I'm having this problem when parsing a json string by `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`.

> Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path '[0].PARENTS', line 4, position 14.

```
List<FormulaDependenciesRespond> jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FormulaDependenciesRespond>>(result);
```

My C# class is:

```
public class FormulaDependenciesRespond {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> parents { get; set; }
}
```

And the Json string is :

```
[
{
    "NAME":"ADC",
    "PARENTS":[
        [
            "CE",
            "CF",
            "CW"
        ]
    ]
}
]
```

I think the problem was in the way that I parsed the double brackets inside "PARENTS". Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Comment: it works for me, are you sure you result variable is having the exact same json you posted.

Comment: Here's your posted code working: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PkOkh7

Comment: I think you are having some new line character in your json, its not clean.

Comment: The error you're seeing would appear if you attempted to do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FormulaDependenciesRespond>(result);`

Comment: Hi Prashant and Andrew. Thanks for your help! Last night I got stuck here for 2 hours so I posted the question. I restart Visual Studio this morning and suddenly it works. I swear I didn't change any of the code or json. Maybe there's cache inside VS I guess because I was using <FormulaDependenciesRespond> instead of a list before. Thanks again